# Example of creating triggers in Cassandra and does this support only for Java?

Tags: cassandra-2.1

Wanted to check about Triggers feature in Cassandra. Can someone please provide an example for creating Trigger.

From this blog,
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support

To create a trigger, you must first build a jar with a class implementing the `ITrigger` interface and put it into the triggers directory on every node, then perform a CQL3 `CREATE TRIGGER` request to tie your trigger to a Cassandra table (or several tables).

As per this info, Triggers in Cassandra are only applicable for Java based applications?

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra 3.0

You can use this and it will get you everything in the insert as a json

```
public class HelloWorld implements ITrigger
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition)
    {
        String tableName = partition.metadata().cfName;
        logger.info("Table: " + tableName);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("message_id", partition.metadata().getKeyValidator().getString(partition.partitionKey().getKey()));

        try {
            UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Unfiltered un = it.next();
                Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();  
                Iterator<Cell> cells = partition.getRow(clt).cells().iterator();
                Iterator<ColumnDefinition> columns = partition.getRow(clt).columns().iterator();

                while(columns.hasNext()){
                    ColumnDefinition columnDef = columns.next();
                    Cell cell = cells.next();
                    String data = new String(cell.value().array()); // If cell type is text
                    obj.put(columnDef.toString(), data);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        logger.debug(obj.toString());

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```