# Apache Cassandra - Listeners

Tags: cassandra, listeners

Is there any listener feature available for cassandra for constatntly checking the table for any update or delete or insert. So if any action is performed in table i should be able to write any third party logic from java and update any other cache.

Comment: Maybe you can use a trigger to respond to an event like this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35161747/1206706

Comment: Not exactly I am expecting trigger .... I am expecting a functionality like listeners concept in hazelcast.... where it would always looking up on the table and if any action is done it would send an ack to Java client code so that I could proceed with third party logic !!!! But in trigger it would be finished in db side itself !!!!