# PubSub or event catching for Cassandra events in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there a PUB-SUB feature for Cassandra using nodejs?

I have a table `TableA` with `TTL value`, If any row in the table got evicted Is there a way to catch the events in nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing...

On server side you can either get changes with CDC, or via triggers (although their use is discouraged). And I'm not really sure that both of these methods will capture expiration via TTL...

Comment: any nodejs example for Triggers?

Comment: No - triggers need to be written in Java because they are executed inside Cassandra. You can look into documentation (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTrigger.html) & examples (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161747/example-of-creating-triggers-in-cassandra-and-does-this-support-only-for-java), but as I mentioned in my answer, it's discouraged to use them as they may heavily impact Cassandra.